# How do I center align every corresponding elements in a table?

Tags: tables, alignment, booktabs

How do I center align every corresponding elements like this? 
Also if the second row is `(y_1+z1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_4 & y_5 & y_6 & y_7+y_3)` would you think that align the parentheses looks better or it just weird to algin the parentheses like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]
  \begin{table}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{A table}
  \label{tab:lable}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
                            \toprule
\textbf{No}& \textbf{Example} \\ \midrule
1    & $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_1, x_5, x_6, x_7)$  \\\midrule
2    & $(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5, y_6, y_7)$  \\\midrule
3    & $(z_1,z_2,-z_8-z_3,z_2,z_5,-z_1-z_4,z_1)$ \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array with ten columns.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\centering
\caption{A table}
\label{tab:lable}

$\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{array}{cc@{}ccccccc @{}c }
\toprule
\textbf{No} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Example}} \\
\midrule
1 & ( & x_1, & x_2, & x_3,     & x_1, & x_5, & x_6,     & x_7 & ) \\
\midrule
2 & ( & y_1, & y_2, & y_3,     & y_4, & y_5, & y_6,     & y_7 & ) \\
\midrule
3 & ( & z_1, & z_2, &-z_8-z_3, & z_2, & z_5, &-z_1-z_4, & z_1 & ) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the redundant rules but some vertical space:

```
$\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{array}{cc@{}ccccccc @{}c }
\toprule
\textbf{No} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Example}} \\
\midrule
1 & ( & x_1, & x_2, & x_3,     & x_1, & x_5, & x_6,     & x_7 & ) \\
\addlinespace
2 & ( & y_1, & y_2, & y_3,     & y_4, & y_5, & y_6,     & y_7 & ) \\
\addlinespace
3 & ( & z_1, & z_2, &-z_8-z_3, & z_2, & z_5, &-z_1-z_4, & z_1 & ) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
```

[image]

Comment: May I know where I can read more about `{cc@{}ccccccc @{}c }`? I have been trying to search but couldn't find it.

Comment: @emnha `c` denotes a center aligned column; `@{}` suppresses insertion of intercolumn space.