# How to align between text and math between two columns?

Tags: tables, alignment, ieeetran, booktabs

Relating to my [previous question and the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653711/how-do-i-center-align-every-corresponding-elements-in-a-table) given by egreg. Now I would like to add one column. 
How can I add more space between these two columns and the text like this?  
Also if you please suggest if you have any idea make it look nicer.

**Add space between two columns:**
[image]
**Algin the text and math in two column:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{array,multirow,bm,adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{table}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{A table}
  \label{tab:table 1}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
$\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{array}{cc@{}cccccccl @{}c }
\toprule
\textbf{No} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Example}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Comment}} \\
\midrule
1 & ( & x_1, & x_2, & x_3,     & x_1, & x_5, & x_6,     & x_7 & ) & \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}This is an example \\of two line text\end{tabular}\\
\addlinespace
2 & ( & y_1, & y_2, & y_3,     & y_4, & y_5, & y_6,     & y_7 & ) &\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}Two lines \\for the second row\end{tabular}\\
\addlinespace
3 & ( & z_1, & z_2, &-z_8-z_3, & z_2, & z_5, &-z_1-z_4, & z_1 & ) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `@{}` has an argument, that may be, e.g., `\hspace`:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{array,multirow,bm,adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[1]
\begin{table}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{A table}
  \label{tab:table 1}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
$\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
%\begin{array}{cc@{}cccccccl @{}c }
\begin{array}{cc@{}cccccccl @{\hspace{9pt}}c }
\toprule
\textbf{No} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Example}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Comment}} \\
\midrule
1 & ( & x_1, & x_2, & x_3,     & x_1, & x_5, & x_6,     & x_7 & ) & \begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}This is an example \\of two line text\end{tabular}\\
\addlinespace
2 & ( & y_1, & y_2, & y_3,     & y_4, & y_5, & y_6,     & y_7 & ) &\begin{tabular}[l]{@{}l@{}}Two lines \\for the second row\end{tabular}\\
\addlinespace
3 & ( & z_1, & z_2, &-z_8-z_3, & z_2, & z_5, &-z_1-z_4, & z_1 & ) \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest that you employ a `tabular*` environment and set its overall width to `\columnwidth`. Then, provide for a bit of extra whitespace to the left of the final (text) column, along the lines used in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,bm}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}  % automatic math mode
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{A table} \label{tab:table 1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{C} @{\quad} l }
\toprule
\textbf{No} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{\textbf{Example}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Comment}} \\
\midrule
1 & (x_1, & x_2, & x_3,     & x_1, & x_5, & x_6,     & x_7) & 
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
    This is an example \\of two line text
    \end{tabular}\\
\addlinespace
2 & (y_1, & y_2, & y_3,     & y_4, & y_5, & y_6,     & y_7) &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}
    Two lines \\for the second row
    \end{tabular}\\
\addlinespace
3 & (z_1, & z_2, &-z_8-z_3, & z_2, & z_5, &-z_1-z_4, & z_1) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have the alignment with the `Shortunderstack` command from `stackengine`. As to the spacing of the last column, add, e.g., `\quad` inside `@{}`:

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,bm,adjustbox}
    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \begin{document}

    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{table}[!t]
      \centering
      \caption{A table}
      \label{tab:table 1}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
    $\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
    \begin{array}{cc@{}cccccccl @{\quad}c }
    \toprule
    \textbf{No} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Example}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Comment}} \\
    \midrule
    1 & ( & x_1, & x_2, & x_3, & x_1, & x_5, & x_6, & x_7 & ) & \Shortunderstack[l]{This is an example \\ of two line text}\\
    \addlinespace
    2 & ( & y_1, & y_2, & y_3, & y_4, & y_5, & y_6, & y_7 & ) & \Shortunderstack[l]{Two lines \\for the second row
    }\\
    \addlinespace
    3 & ( & z_1, & z_2, &-z_8-z_3, & z_2, & z_5, &-z_1-z_4, & z_1 & ) \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{array}$
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]